# How to use Jar Launcher with specified jdk version

Tags: macos, java

Now I have multiple jdk installed on OSX as shown below:

```
└─[1] <> /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    14.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 14.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_241, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Then I want to double click to run a jar file directly, for instance this:

[image: jar file]

However, it warns me that this jar file is launched with JDK 14 but I want to launch it with JDK 1.8. 

A solution is that run it in terminal with "java -jar" in specified jdk path,but clearly it is not elegant.

The best way is to let "Jar Launcher" use specified jdk version ,but I don't know how.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After long time efforts,I finally find the solution,that is ,to make your own Jar Launcher app:

1. Launch Automator to make Automator Quick Action

   [image]
2. Select Application
3. Look for the Run Shell Script action with Filter Finder Items  and add it to 
   the right.
4. paste scripts here like this below:

   [image]
   I make some changes to make it better

```bsh
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
cd "$(dirname "$@")" 
java -jar "$@"
```

5. save this quick action as an app for example "open jar.app"
6. go to  /System/Library/CoreServices/Jar Launcher.app/Contents/Resources
   and copy JarLauncher.icns
   [image]
7. cd to "open jar.app" you just made and paste JarLauncher.icns to 
   "open jar.app/Contents/Resources"
8. edit  "open jar.app/Contents/Info.plist" and change key(AutomatorApplet to JarLauncher.icns):

```
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>JarLauncher.icns</string>
```

[image]

9. now you can choose to open with "open jar.app" just like before.
   [image]